# Replication issue after server restart

Tags: sql-server, database, database-replication, restart, transactional-replication

We restarted both the publisher database & subscription database (distributor & subscription are on same database). All the replications process has stopped like daily, weekly & Transactional replication.

When I checked the properties of the publication I got the error

> SQL Server cannot retrieve the information for publication ‘dbSQL-Transactional’ in dbsql-01.

When I check the status of the snapshot & logreader agent I got this error

> unable to display agent status

and on the replication monitor, it says the error is

> The process could not execute 'sp_repldone/sp_replcounters' on 'dbsql-01'.

Do I have to recreate all the replication on both the servers? Does it save a copy of the publisher's config, as there are some tables in daily replication, some tables in weekly & some in transactional?